# NoReverseMatch at /abampdb/get/ in django

Tags: django, django-urls, django-url-reverse

i am encountering a problem

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'show-protein' not found. 'show-protein' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

```
<form method="GET" action="">
74          <label for="q">Search:</label>
75          <input type="text" name="q" value="{{ request.GET.q }}" placeholder="Enter search keyword">
76          <button type="submit">Search</button> {{ form.as_p }}
77  
78          <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search...">
79          <tbody>
80              {% for protein in protein_list %}
81  
82              <tr>
83                  <td><a href="{% url 'show-protein' %}">{{ protein }}</a></td>
84                  <td>{{ protein.weight }}</td>
85                  <td>{{ protein.hydroph }}</td>
86                  <td><input type="radio" name="name" value="{{ protein.name }}"></td>
87                  <td>{{ protein.name }}</td>
88                  {% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .import views
from .views import *

app_name = "abampdb"
urlpatterns = [
    path('get/', views.get_search_results, name='get-list'),
    path('show_protein/<protein_id>', views.show_protein, name='show-protein'),
]
```

main urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('abampdb/', include('abampdb.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

this is my gs109 urls.py i have included the abampdb urls i have tried to include abampdb:show-protein in url but still getting error

upd:

```
NoReverseMatch at /abampdb/get/
Reverse for 'show-protein' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['abampdb/show_protein/(?P<proteins_id>[^/]+)\\Z']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/abampdb/get/
Django Version: 4.0.5
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'show-protein' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['abampdb/show_protein/(?P<proteins_id>[^/]+)\\Z']
```

here is my updated template

```
 <form method="GET" action="">
74          <label for="q">Search:</label>
75          <input type="text" name="q" value="{{ request.GET.q }}" placeholder="Enter search keyword">
76          <button type="submit">Search</button> {{ form.as_p }}
77  
78          <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search...">
79          <tbody>
80              {% for protein in protein_list %}
81  
82              <tr>
83                  <td><a href="{% url 'abampdb:show-protein' protein.id %}">{{ protein }}</a></td>
```

my models file

```
class Proteins(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    hydroph = models.CharField(max_length=70)
```

my views

```
def show_protein(request, proteins_id):
    protein = Proteins().objects.get(pk=proteins_id)
    return render(request, 'abampdb/show_protein.html', {'protein': protein})

def get_search_results(request):

    dock_list = Docks.objects.all()
    protein_list = Proteins.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'abampdb/custom_view.html', {'dock_list': dock_list, 'protein_list': protein_list})
```

please see i don't know what I am doing anything wrong. i am a beginner in this.

Solved and updated the url with

```
{% url 'abampdb:show-protein' proteins_id=protein.pk %}
```

final Template

````
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search...">
        <tbody>
            {% for protein in protein_list %} {{ protein.id }}

            <tr>
                <td><a href="{% url 'abampdb:show-protein' proteins_id=protein.pk %}">{{ protein.name }}</a></td>

                <td>{{ protein.weight }}</td>
                <td>{{ protein.hydroph }}</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="name" value="{{ protein.name }}"></td>
                <td>{{ protein.name }}</td>```
````

Comment: Are you including this `urls.py` in another one?

Comment: yes from gs109 i have created another app abampdb
gs109.abampdb.urls.app_name

Comment: Edit your question and post that `urls.py` as well. You should use the namespace in your `{% url %}` tag.

Comment: how ? can you please guide?

Comment: i have edited the url like that <td><a href="{% url 'show-protein' protein.id %}">{{ protein }}</a></td> 

but still showing error of  NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'show-protein' not found. 'show-protein' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: Please read my comment again. You should edit your question to include the contents of your main `urls.py`.

Comment: i have edited my question with main urls.py

Comment: There is something wrong with the whole setup, perhaps you have multiple files with the same name in different locations which enable _magic_ failures. The last error says it tried to match url pattern with parameter `proteins_id` however shown urls.py states `<protein_id>` - without "s". Try to clean up project folder contents. Also try switching here `{% url 'abampdb:show-protein' protein.id %}` from `protein.id` to `protein.pk`, also it worth a try to switch to kwards: `{% url 'abampdb:show-protein' proteins_id=protein.pk %}`.

Comment: And put some additional code for debugging purpose into this template: print out what is protein, protein.id, protein.pk.

Comment: Thankyou resolved my error with {% url 'abampdb:show-protein' proteins_id=protein.pk %}

Answer (score 0):

Since you set this `app_name = "abampdb"` urls should be referenced with namespace and argument `protein_id` is required as per url pattern definition:

`<a href="{% url 'abampdb:show-protein' proteins_id=protein.id %}">`

[Example from docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#id5)

Comment: i have added but still showing error

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'show-protein' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['abampdb/show_protein/(?P<proteins_id>[^/]+)\\Z']

Comment: At least url resolver falls into correct url pattern now. But `protein` is null or `protein.id` is empty. Are you sure that all url reversions are inside `{% for protein in protein_list %}`? Please update your question with modified code and current error traceback (make additional `upd: ` block in the question).

Comment: updated the answer with final version